# How to convert screen position to isometric position

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas, isometric

How to convert the screen position (X,Y) to an isometric position?

I have code that converts the isometric position to the screen position here: http://jsfiddle.net/CR3JS/

This is the formula axis: http://s15.postimage.org/xyxfukxkp/iso_Axis.jpg

And my question is: How to convert the screen position (X,Y) to an isometric position?

Something like:

```
screenToIsometric(144, 88) -> X: 10, Y: 0, Z: 1
```

Comment: How many degrees would you like to rotate by? It's all a matter of multiplying (144, 88,0) by a rotation matrix http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions

Of course once you have the angle this can be simplified into multiplying the x and y values by constants to get x y z and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

You can't have one single X,Y,Z point, because one 2D screen position will map to several different tiles - one at each different Z levels. If you trying to figure on what object in isometric view user did click, easiest, though somewhat dirty way would be just loop over all Z levels starting from upper to lower, use reverse of formula in your sample function and check if there's anything suitable for click at position, proceeding to lower level if this place is empty.